# Missing symbol 'for_realloc_lhs' in Matlab's libifcorem​d.dll'

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex, intel-fortran

I built a `toto.dll` and a `toto.lib` with `ifort` (Intel's 2017 update 4 fortran compiler). Then I used `mex` matlab's compiler to produce several `mexw64` files.

When I used `mex` I linked to `toto.lib`. Then, I ran a `.m` file (matlab file) inside matlab 2017a 64bits (under win10 64bits), an this file is using functions from the various `mexw64`'s I compiled.

In the matlab file, at the first call of such function I got the following error :

```
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\path\to\mexfile.mexw64': Missing symbol 'for_realloc_lhs'
in 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a/bin/win64\libifcoremd.dll' required by 'C:\path\to\mexfile.mexw64'.
```

My fortran compiler is intel fortran 2017 update 4.

I found this :

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/726858

but it does not help that much as for me :

- replacing the matlab dll by the intel fortran is not a viable (nor correct) solution (it hides the real problem)
- [asking mathworks](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/412974-missing-symbol-for_realloc_lhs-in-c-program-files-matlab-r2017a-bin-win64-libifcoremd-dll) yielded no answer so far ... (hence my post here)

Can't I somehow tell to matlab to look for the `libifcoremd.dll'` in the intel fortran directory first, instead of looking in the matlab directory ? (I tried `addpath` inside the `.m` file, without success.) What should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

If Matlab includes libifcoremd.dll in the same folder as the Matlab executable, which is a horrible thing for them to do, you can't override it. My advice would be to delete the Intel compiler DLLs from that location, though they will likely return on an update.

If they're in a separate folder named on PATH, make sure that the Intel folder is first on PATH.

Probably the best approach for you is to build your DLL to be linked against the static libraries (Fortran > Libraries > Use Run-Time Library > Multithreaded (/MT)). Then you won't be at the mercy of Matlab's bad behavior. I recommend this only when the caller of your DLL is not Fortran.

Comment: Matlab indeed includes libifcoremd.dll in the same folder as the matlab executables. The intel compiler dlls are not in the same folder (thx God). (I am under windows 10, don't know what happens on Unix/Linux ...) I will try tonight your folder orderered linking as well as the linking to static libraries. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Actually, I am on a code originally running on linux, so that I am using command line `ifort` on my windows 10 for now, and I don't really understand the "Fortran > Libraries > Use Run-Time Library > Multithreaded (/MT)" visual studio bit for now. (Though it reminds me of some intel MKL option in visual studio). I will try to achieve it command line wise, and when everything will be working correctly, I will port it in visual studio.

Comment: From the command line, use /MT or /libs:static when building your DLL.

Comment: Initially I compiled as follows : `"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin\win64\mex.exe" -largeArrayDims toto.f totog.F mylib.lib -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin\win64"` (where for sake of completeness `mylib.lib` is compiled through `ifort -c -fpp file1.f90` then `ifort -c -fpp file2.f90` then `ifort -c -fpp file3.f90` then `xilib /out:./libfinal.lib file1.obj file2.obj file3.obj`) and had the "Missing symbol 'for_realloc_lhs' in 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a/bin/win64\libifcoremd.dll" error.

Comment: Now I compile with `"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin\win64\mex.exe" -largeArrayDims toto.f totog.F mylib.lib -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.124\windows\redist\intel64_win\compiler" -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin\win64"` as "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.124\windows\redist\intel64_win\compiler" contains `libifcoremd.dll` but I still have the same error as in my above comment.

Comment: What I don't understand is that I start compiling `mylib.lib` from a command prompt opened by running the intel 2018 `ipsxe-comp-vars.bat`, but when I do the `"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin\win64\mex.exe" ...` compilations, it writes "Building with 'Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017 for Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015'" in the same command prompt. How is that even possible ?...

Comment: I have never used Matlab, but I'd guess that the Matlab script that combines your library with Matlab is coded to use the older versions - perhaps that's what was current when you installed. You'd have to dig into Matlab to see. Of course, Matlab has no clue which version of the tools you used to build your library.

Answer (score 0):

I have met with similar issue. I have compiled the DLL from Intel Fortran Compiler, and called it from MatLab. But when running in MatLab, it complained that missing symbol 'for_realloc_lhs'.
The solution is to change the compiling option in Intel Fortran compiling setting from menu "project-->Fortran-->Libraries-->Runtime Library-->Multithreaded". default option is Multithread DLL(/libs;dll/threads). The idea is to change the dynamic dll linking during runtime to static dll.

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: How does this answer differ from Steve Lionel's answer?