# Unresolved external symbol "for_realloc_lhs" at compilation

Tags: c, visual-studio, fortran, linker-errors

I am trying to compile a SDK with pre-built Fortran libraries.
The SDK requires Intel Fortran redistributables libraries parallel studio XE 2017.
When trying to compile the SDK's example files, i get multiple errors: **LNK2001 "unresolved external symol _for_realloc_lhs"**

From what i read, this could be caused by the SDK's fortran library being compiled with a version of the Intel's fortran compiler that is too old.
([see here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/redistributables-for-intel-parallel-studio-xe-2017-composer-edition-for-windows)), however i do not own the SDK's fortran sources thus, i could not recompile them.

I would like to know if i am missing someting here or if the SDK's fortran library was imply built with the wrong tools.

[EDIT]
i read what you said (thanks for your very clear explanation) and it seems my problem is really close to what you just explained, i seem to link against the 11.1 version of Intel redistributables. However, it seems that the library i got on Intel's website does not feature all the files the linker is looking for. (or at least i could not find them).
There is the command visual studio used.
Unfortunately, i am unable at the moment to produce the log, as it exceeds maximum message size.

Here is a summarized version of the log

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Tutorials, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>
1>  Searching libraries
1>      Searching ..\..\lib\CK_IO.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\kernel32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\user32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\gdi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\winspool.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\comdlg32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\advapi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\shell32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\ole32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\oleaut32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\uuid.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbc32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbccp32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\legacy_stdio_definitions.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\LIBCMT.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\libvcruntime.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x86\libucrt.lib:
1>      Searching ..\..\lib\CK_IO.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\kernel32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\user32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\gdi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\winspool.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\comdlg32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\advapi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\shell32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\ole32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\oleaut32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\uuid.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbc32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbccp32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\legacy_stdio_definitions.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\LIBCMT.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\libvcruntime.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x86\libucrt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\ifconsol.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\libifcoremt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\libmmt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\libirc.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\svml_dispmt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\ImageHlp.lib:
1>      Searching ..\..\lib\CK_IO.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\kernel32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\user32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\gdi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\winspool.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\comdlg32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\advapi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\shell32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\ole32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\oleaut32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\uuid.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbc32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbccp32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\legacy_stdio_definitions.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\LIBCMT.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\libvcruntime.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x86\libucrt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\ifconsol.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\libifcoremt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\libmmt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\libirc.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\svml_dispmt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\ImageHlp.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib:
1>      Searching ..\..\lib\CK_IO.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\kernel32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\user32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\gdi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\winspool.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\comdlg32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\advapi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\shell32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\ole32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\oleaut32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\uuid.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbc32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbccp32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\legacy_stdio_definitions.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\LIBCMT.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\libvcruntime.lib:
1>
1>  Finished searching libraries
1>
1>  Searching libraries
1>      Searching ..\..\lib\CK_IO.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\kernel32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\user32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\gdi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\winspool.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\comdlg32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\advapi32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\shell32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\ole32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\oleaut32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\uuid.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbc32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\odbccp32.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\legacy_stdio_definitions.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\LIBCMT.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\libvcruntime.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x86\libucrt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\ifconsol.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\libifcoremt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\libmmt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\libirc.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\fortran\Lib\ia32\svml_dispmt.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\ImageHlp.lib:
1>      Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib:
1>
1>  Finished searching libraries
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I would also like to mention that the directory in which the redistributables are supposed to be installed (as mentioned [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/redistributables-for-intel-parallel-studio-xe-2017-composer-edition-for-windows) : "redist[ia32|intel64]\mpirt (for Fortran packages)") there is no library named libifcore...
Actually, there is almost nothing that looks like anything that i need to link.) [an image of the mentionned folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMq3h.png)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641751/missing-symbol-for-realloc-lhs-in-matlabs-libifcoremd-dll

Comment: What exactly are you compiling and how? See [mcve].

Comment: How exactly did you install the redistributable library? Why are you looking into the directory you show? Which directory is that?

Comment: I followed the install instructions mentioned on the page i gave a link to and the folder is what should contain the libraries as indicated on intel's website (this folder is also pointed by environement variables created when installing the libraries)

Comment: %INTEL_DEV_REDIST%redist\ia32_win\mpirt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a nit. The error is coming from the link step, not compiling. Contrary to your guess about the compiler version used for the library being "too old", instead it's the set of Intel libraries (redistributables) you're linking against that are too old (or missing?) If you are truly linking against the 2017-version libraries, that routine should be in libifcore. Double and triple check how you are doing the link and which libraries you name, if any, in the link step.

An easy way to see what's going on is to add the linker option /verbose to the link step. You haven't shown how you build the application and which command is used for linking. If you're using Visual Studio, set the project property `Linker > General > Show Progress` to "Display all progress messages". If using the ifort command, add at the end `/link /verbose` If using some other command, look at its documentation to see how you should specify link options. Capture the linker output (build log or whatever) - it will name each library it searches and which symbols come from where.

It may be as simple a matter as making sure you name the Intel libraries after the SDK libraries in the link step.

If this doesn't help, edit your question to add the commands you're using to link (compile doesn't matter) and show the actual output (do not summarize).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, it didnt solve my problem yet. i updated my message

Comment: Also, i found a file called libifcore.so, howver no .lib and when i try to link it , the linker declares it corrupted.

Comment: I updated my post to add a little more detail on my problems.

Comment: The package you downloaded with libifcore.so was for Linux. The linker output you show indicates that libifcoremt.lib is found - this is the static version of libifcore. If you installed the 11.1 version of the redistributables, that would explain the error. Download the latest redistributable package, even if you are using the 11.1 compiler.

Comment: In that case, i really dont understand. on [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compilers-redistributable-libraries-by-version) page, i went for the Parallel Studio XE 2017 (all Editions) on the bottom left side on the windows tab and i went for the update 8 of Intel fortran compiler for windows. you saying i installed linux libraries really confuses me, where did i do wrong?

Comment: By the way, by reading a little more on Intel's website, it appears that whatever the installer installed, it did it inside: Program Files(x86)/common files/intel  instead of Program Files(x86)/IntelSWTools/... Also, the visual studio project that i was handed is preconfigured and it tries to look inside IntelSWTools/compiles_and_libraries_2017.1.143/windows/compiler/lib/ia32_win Which makes me belive someting went wrong with the installation, but i dont get what or why.

Comment: No, nothing went wrong. That's where the files should go. Your project is assuming that a specific version of the compiler is installed, not the redistributables. Change that path to be the one with ifcoremt.lib and it should link.

Comment: But there are no .lib files in my install. i really dont understand. Where am i supposed to get these? should i install someting else than what i downloaded on: [This page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/redistributables-for-intel-parallel-studio-xe-2017-composer-edition-for-windows)? (my visual studio project requires Update 1)

Comment: Let's continue this discussion at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/807251 rather than spreading it out, though you can indicate the resolution here when you have it. The Intel redistributables no longer provide static libraries and the entry point you need was new in the 2017 compiler version.